# PHP UPDATE acting as INSERT

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

So. I'm studying `PHP/MySQLi` atm and for that I'm doing a movie-database. I'm a newb at PHP and I've searched for 3 days through the web for someone with the same issue but I have not found anything.

My issue is that I need an `EDIT` button so it's possible to `EDIT` whatever you `INSERT`.

The problem i'm facing is that my `edit.php` which has the prepared statement for `UPDATING` my table is acting as `INSERT` and is just putting in a new row with a new ID.

```
<?php // edit.php
require_once 'movie_form.php';
if (isset($_POST['id']))
{
            $id =$_POST['id'];

            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE filmer SET Title = ?, Director = ?, Year = ?, Category = ? WHERE id = ?");
            $stmt->bind_param('ssiii', $_POST['Title'], $_POST['Director'], $_POST['Year'], $_POST['Category'], $_POST['id']);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();
        }
?>
```

I'm echoing my ID im getting from the other page, it's the correct ID for the movie i clicked EDIT on. It still creates a new ID unfortunately and I don't understand why.

Comment: This may seem stupid, but are you sure you're calling your `edit.php` script and not your `insert.php` (or whatever) script? I'm ashamed to admit it but I once had that problem myself! Felt stupid for days afterwards...

Comment: To make it short: what you're describing is **impossible**, that's not how an `UPDATE` statement works. Ever. Your bug is elsewhere. Most likely `movie_form.php` contains and executes an `INSERT` statement.

Comment: Alternatively, take a look at INSERT... UPDATE ON DUPLICATE KEY

Comment: Consider enabling query logging. It will allow you to see queries that are executed, which will help to confirm or disprove Niet's suspicion. Also, take a look at your web server log to see which URL is accessed. If you map your script names to your URLs, you may be able to easily determine which script is being called.

Comment: Yeah, i'll do that even tho im 100% sure im not calling the wrong script since i've replaced the edit code from the edit.php  with my delete code and it deletes just  fine.

I'll be back as soon i've got more information.

Answer (score 0):

Please correct this

```
   $id =$POST_['id'];
```

to

```
  $id =$_POST['id'];
```

Comment: Yeah, this was just a recent mistake, didnt change the behaviour. Ty for noticing tho!